# How can I get Liferay user ID from a external servlet

Tags: liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6, vaadin7

I have a problem. I want to get Liferay user ID in a servlet that runs in another Tomcat, not in Tomcat on which Liferay runs. If both runs in same Tomcat, no problem, Liferay API works perfectly. But in this case, when I use 'UserLocalServiceUtil.decryptUserId' in order to decrypt user ID present in cookie, I get a 'BeanLocator is null' exception.

What can I do? Has this any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can consume Liferay's web services to get User details from Liferay from your servlet. You can choose from [SOAP WebServices](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/soap-web-services-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en) or [JSON WebServices](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/json-web-services-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en).

My recommendation in you scenario is to use JSON WebService - get-user-by-email-address method (like this: `http://<host>:<port>/api/jsonws?signature=/user/get-user-by-email-address-2-companyId-emailAddress`) to get User object, and get UserId from it.